# any way to trigger a method in WCF REST at the start of the the Service

Tags: global-asax, wcf-rest

Can we make any method to fire everytime when a service is started/called...irrespective of operation the service performs.
Just like Application_BeginRequest() in Global.asax in web applications

Comment: A constructor sounds good (maybe static, should try and see)

Comment: tried...but unable to make it..i may be doing wrond...can u share any code

Comment: You got it backwards: *you* should share *your* non-working code so the community can help you fix it